# Java GridPane mid section issue

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a Login UI using GridPane. My window opens in 300 x 300 & I have set the row & column indices to certain values such that both my texts "USER ID" & "PASSWORD" appear at the center of the window (at equal distance from all four sides). It appears like this

[image: this]

The **problem** occurs when I maximize the window, those two fields (USER ID & PASSWORD) don't stay at the center of the maximized window anymore & it results in this

[image]

I have tried placing the GridPane at the center of a BorderPane, but didn't work out. How do I make those two maintain their position at all times?

Here's the following code:

```
void tryGridPaneFunc()
{
 main.setTitle("GridPane Try");
 BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
 GridPane grid = new GridPane();
 Text usr = new Text("USER ID:");
 Text pwd = new Text("PASSWORD:");

 grid.add(usr, 18,20);
 grid.add(pwd, 18, 21);
 grid.setHgap(10);
 grid.setVgap(10);
 grid.setPadding(new Insets(20));
 //grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);


 HBox empty1 = new HBox();
 empty1.setPadding(new Insets(40));
 HBox empty2 = new HBox();
 empty2.setPadding(new Insets(40));
 HBox empty3 = new HBox();
 empty3.setPadding(new Insets(40));
 HBox empty4 = new HBox();
 empty4.setPadding(new Insets(40));


 empty1.setHgrow(empty1, Priority.ALWAYS);
 empty2.setHgrow(empty1, Priority.ALWAYS);
 empty3.setHgrow(empty1, Priority.ALWAYS);
 empty4.setHgrow(empty1, Priority.ALWAYS);


 root.setTop(empty1);
 root.setBottom(empty2);
 root.setLeft(empty3);
 root.setRight(empty4);

 root.setCenter(grid);

 Scene msc = new Scene(root,500,500);

 main.setScene(msc);

 main.show();
}
```

I'm sorry if such posts already exist. They didn't show up when I searched. Hence, if you find any, please provide the link to it.

Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding empty regions and using empty rows and columns in the grid pane shouldn't be necessary. `GridPane` has an [alignment property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#alignmentProperty) for setting "The alignment of of the grid within the gridpane's width and height.". So all you need here is `grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);`.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CenteredGridPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage main) {
        main.setTitle("GridPane Try");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        Text usr = new Text("USER ID:");
        Text pwd = new Text("PASSWORD:");

        grid.add(usr, 0, 0);
        grid.add(pwd, 0, 1);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);

        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene msc = new Scene(grid,500,500);

        main.setScene(msc);

        main.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```